# how to configure multiple filters to one end point

Tags: apache, apache-camel

i one to apply multiple filters to same end point in apache camel.
i have tried like this but it is not correct.

```
<camel:endpoint id="inputpath" uri="file:///${sourcefolder}/XYZ/?move=.success&amp;moveFailed=.Error;recursive=true&amp;filter=#ghFilter;filter=#myAntFilter" />
```

it seems it is not the proper way because i got the exception.
Please suggest how to use multiple filters in the same endpoint.

Comment: First of all, what is the exception you are getting? Then I'd suggest that you combine the filters into a single bean rather than trying to apply two different ones. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Not very confirmed with your demand, but I think   multicast(http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html) can be helpful.

one example

```
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:test123" />
        <multicast parallelProcessing="true">
            <filter>
                <method ref="camelBean" method="match1" />
                <to uri="activemq:QUEUE1" />
            </filter>
            <filter>
                <method ref="camelBean" method="match2" />
                <to uri="activemq:QUEUE2" />
            </filter>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple filters. Only one filter is supported. But you can just from your filter java code do multiple filtering yourself.